# JTable CellEditor Format

Tags: java, mysql, swing

i have a JTable filled with mySQL database.
one of the columns is filled with dates in mySQL Format of (yyyy/MM/dd)
i used a cell renderer to show the date on te column as (dd/MM/yyyy) with this class:

```
    static class DateRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private Date dateValue;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdfNewValue = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    private String valueToString = "";

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        if ((value != null)) {
            String stringFormat = value.toString();
            try {
                dateValue = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(stringFormat);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            valueToString = sdfNewValue.format(dateValue);
            value = valueToString;
            setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.CENTER );
        }
        super.setValue(value);
    }
    }
```

and i have set it to the proper column on the JTable using

table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new DateRenderer());

the issue i am having is that the cells are editable, once i double click a cell in that column the date looks as (yyyy/MM/dd) again.

i have tried using a custom class to show the cell editing diffrently using this code

```
class MyEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
      public MyEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
      }

      public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
          int row, int column) {
        JTextField editor = (JTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected,
            row, column);
        editor.setFont(font);
        String ndate=new String();

        if (dataModel.getColumnName(3)=="date" && column==3) {
            String s=(String) dataModel.getValueAt(row, column);
             SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
             SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
               try {
                 Date odate = originalFormat.parse(s);
                 ndate=(targetFormat.format(odate));

                } catch (ParseException ex) {

                   }
            value=ndate;

        }

        if (value != null) {
          editor.setText(value.toString());
          editor.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        }
        return editor;
      }
    }
```

it works perfect but the only issue that i cannot resolve is that the mySQL database is being update when cells are being changed on the JTable, and mySQL doesnt receive dates in dd/mm/yyyy format so im looking for a way that once the editing is finished it will transfer back the date to mySQL acceptable fromat of yyyy/mm/dd.

anybody can please help me to resolve this issue?

Regards.

Comment: You should be storing a `Date` object in the table, not a String representing the date. Then you pass the Date object to your SQL.

Comment: thanks for the response i will look into its later on, worst case scenario i will just update my method for updating the sql database.